# What does 今一概に言える equate to? "Now, unconditionally said thing?"

Tags: grammar, meaning, phrases

I was watching a 45 second video, but ran into some trouble with the above. I will post the entire subtitles for context purposes.

> テレビ番組を勝手にアップロードするのは違法だからな
>   10年以下の懲役か1000万円以下の罰金か、その両方だが
>   それって受験に関係ありますか
>   受験だけが人生じゃないだろう、お前
>   でもまだ未成年です
>   未成年自慢すんなよ、お前
>   未成年だろうが成人だろうが、違法なものは違法なんだぞ
>   でも10年の懲役って重くないですか？
>   重いかどうか**今一概に言える**ことじゃないなぁ
>   とにかく、違法な事はやっちゃあいけないってことだ
>   なんだ、おれ説教臭いか？
>   おれ説教臭いか？
>   おれ説教臭いか？
>   説教臭いと思う奴？
>   [音楽]
>   それ、違法です！！

Disclaimer: English subs below may not be correct

> It's illegal to freely upload TV shows.
>   By law you can get up to 10 years of hard labor... ...10 million yen in fines... ...or you could get both.
>   Does that have anything to do with the exam?
>   Exams are not the only things in life, mind you.
>   But we are still minors.
>   Do not boast about being a minor, you.
>   Whether be it a minor or an adult, illegal acts are illegal.
>   But isn't 10 years of imprisonment with hard labor excessive?
>   It is not something that can generally be said categorically whether it is heavy or not!
>   Anyway, do not do illegal acts.
>   What is it, am I being preachy?
>   Am I being preachy?
>   Am I being preachy?
>   Who thinks I'm being too preachy?
>   [Music]
>   That's illegal!

Comment: I can't find the text in your question in the provided text, so I am not sure how this is providing context at all.

Comment: @psosuna https://www.reddit.com/r/translator/comments/cbh90h/japaneseenglish_%E6%94%BE%E9%80%81%E7%95%AA%E7%B5%84%E3%81%AE%E9%81%95%E6%B3%95%E9%85%8D%E4%BF%A1%E6%92%B2%E6%BB%85%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9A%E3%83%BC%E3%83%B3_%E5%A5%B3%E5%AD%90%E9%AB%98%E7%AF%87/

Comment: Turns out my eyes were reading over the question text a little too fast and I had just missed the phrase. Thank you for the link as well.

Answer (score 3):

一概に on its own is not "unconditionally" but "collectively" or "generically". 一概に言う/一概に述べる means "to say (something) collectively" or "to describe a generalized rule/answer/characteristic".

- **一概に言う**: to describe (something) collectively
- **一概に言える**: to be able to describe (something) collectively
- **一概に言えること**: (relative clause) something that one can describe collectively

Therefore 一概に言えることじゃない means "It's not something I can describe collectively" or "It's hard to give a generalized rule/answer". 今 before it is just "for now".